# Find out which process has locked a file or folder in Windows Server 2016 in the past

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-management, windows-server-2016, lock

Does Windows Server 2016 have any logging available for which process has locked a file in the past?  For example, if a process is failing while trying to access a file because that file is locked by another process but when you go to check the file later it is no longer locked by either process.

Comment: I don't think so.  You can setup audits for actual file access I think but these won't show you the flags used to open the file.  When the process you are running fails, does it return a code to the operating system?  If so, wrap it in a script and call [handle.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) after the failure.  Dump those results to a file and you will probably have your culprit. You can also use handle (as admin) to force close the handle but proceed with caution if you do this.  You can leave the file in an inoperable state depending on factors.

Comment: Procmon may be useful, but will require you to filter and work through quite a bit of information.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Totally agreed @FrankThomas .. nice point (that is what I would also do) .. unfortunately, procmon comes with a very heavy toll of system performance as it looks at everything regardless of what you are filtering.  This might be the better tool depending on the OPs environment and needs.

Comment: If you decide to go with @FrankThomas suggestion, "touch" the file in some way, right click on the entry in procmon and filter things ONLY including that file path.